# Angular Navigate to home after Google Login

Tags: angular, angularfire

I want to send the user to home after successful google login.
This is my login method in the Login component:

```
login()
  {
    this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
    .then((result) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
         this.router.navigate(['']);
       })
  })
}
```

And this is a portion of my app.module.ts:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
      path:'',
      component:HomeComponent
    },
```

This seems to do nothing and routing isn't taking place .
Am I missing anything?

Comment: is your authentication successful? can you put a console log before router navigate and check?

Comment: Yes , I am getting google username after authentication and it is displayed but no routing...

Comment: Try this: this.router.navigateByUrl('/');

Comment: No success @Ritesh.

Comment: This works for me:    this.router.navigate(['/']), See this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-angular-fyfkds?file=app%2Fusers%2Fuser%2Fuser.component.ts, go to users tab, click one of the user and wait for some time, it will redirect to home